# Should "parent" not be used as javascript variable name (reserved words)

Tags: javascript

I've often used the word "parent" as a JavaScript variable name, and have never had any problems.

I've recently learned that "parent" can refer to something else such as when used to access an element in an IFrame's parent such as `parent.document.getElementById("someID")`.

Should I stop using the word "parent" as a JavaScript variable name, and go through all my existing script to change it?  Note that http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/0779sbks%28v=vs.94%29.aspx and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words do not indicate that I shouldn't.

Comment: You can always get to `window` properties with an explicit reference to the global object, so there's really no problem with "parent".

Comment: I think you're fine with it as is.  But I always err on the side of caution and use more descriptive variable names.  Like instead of "parent" I would say "submitButtonParent", or something like that.  Just for readability purposes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

'parent' is not a reserved word but a global object in the browser's execution environment. Whether or not you want to have a variable name that conflicts with that is your decision.

For reference, here is a list of actual reserved words in JS:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Answer (score 6):

If it makes sense for your variable to be called `parent` then go ahead and name it that, you just need to be aware that it will shadow the `parent` property of the `window` object (the global scope), but that's not an issue since you can explicitly reference that using `window.parent` rather than just `parent` wherever you need to work with it.

The only time it should become an issue is if there is code that shares scope with your `parent` variable which is attempting to access `window.parent` without explicitly specifying that they want the property, and that's probably an indication that the code needs to be tweaked.

Answer (score 4):

"JavaScript" isn't the same as "ecosystem within which JavaScript is executed".

Browsers have the `window` and `document` references, which have properties... like `parent`. You can still reference the global parent. If your parent is called on a different object there's no collision anyway.